# Crash jetpack compose Carousel Searching for active node in inactive hierarchy

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, carousel, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-material3

help to solve the issue java.lang.IllegalStateException: Searching for active node in inactive hierarchy.
We used bellow code into Android TV with jetpack compose. it will happen when Carousel focus move multiple time.

```
`Carousel(
    modifier = modifier
        .padding(start = padding.start)
        .border(
            width = JetStreamBorderWidth,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = if (isCarouselFocused) 1f else 0f),
            shape = ShapeDefaults.Medium,
        )
        .clip(ShapeDefaults.Medium)
        .onFocusChanged {
            Log.d("Carousel","Carousel hasFocus:${it.hasFocus} isFocused:${it.isFocused}")
            // Because the carousel itself never gets the focus
            isCarouselFocused = it.hasFocus

        }
        .semantics {
            contentDescription =
                StringConstants.Composable.ContentDescription.MoviesCarousel
        }
        .handleDPadKeyEvents(onEnter = {
            goToVideoPlayer(movies[carouselState.activeItemIndex])
        }),
    autoScrollDurationMillis = 2500,
    itemCount = movies.size,
    carouselState = carouselState,
    carouselIndicator = {
        CarouselIndicator(
            itemCount = movies.size,
            activeItemIndex = carouselState.activeItemIndex
        )
    },
    contentTransformStartToEnd = fadeIn(tween(durationMillis = 100))
        .togetherWith(fadeOut(tween(durationMillis = 100))),
    contentTransformEndToStart = fadeIn(tween(durationMillis = 100))
        .togetherWith(fadeOut(tween(durationMillis = 100))),
    content = { index ->
        val movie = movies[index]
        // background
        CarouselItemBackground(movie = movie, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        // foreground
        CarouselItemForeground(
            movie = movie,
            isCarouselFocused = isCarouselFocused,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
    }
)`
```

I have tried handleDPadKeyEvents left/right prevention, but it's not right solution. may be it's library issue. I used library ' implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")'

Comment: I am having a hard time reproducing the issue and understanding your use case. Can you please post images of your desired behavior?

Comment: Sure let me a video and then after will share a link